# How to run a Node.js worker for a server hosted on Amazon ECS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, npm

we have a node server on Amazon ECS that gets hit around 100 times per second. Since javascript is single threaded, we don't want to block the event loop. So we need to create a worker that periodically fetches data from a database and loads the data into memory. This may take a while, so we want to create a worker so there's a different event loop. How can we do this with ECS? Can we just use an npm or do we have to do anything special like setting additional stuff up on the Amazon console to have a separate worker?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can use the [cluster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) module to take advantage of multi-core systems, that will improve the load the server can take.

**Basic cluster example**

```
const cluster = require( 'cluster' );
const express = require( 'express' );

const port    = 3000;
const numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  console.log(`Master ${process.pid} is running`);

  // Fork workers.
  for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }

  cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
    console.log(`worker ${worker.process.pid} died`);
  });

} else {
  let app = express();

  app.get('/', (req, res) => {
      res.send('Hello World!');
  });

  app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`App listening on port ${port}!`);
  });
}
```

**AWS**

You can use [AWS Elastic Load Balancing](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/?nc1=h_ls) which will load balance between multiple EC2 instances.
Then you can scale your EC2 capacity up or down automatically with [auto scaling](https://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/?nc1=h_ls).

Auto scaling will launch N number of instances, which your load balancer will send traffic to, when your server reaches certain threshold. This way you have multiple EC2 instances serving requests.

> So we need to create a worker that periodically fetches data from a
>   database and loads the data into memory.

You can have a worker EC2 instance (This instance won't be taking requests, so you shouldn't add it to the load balancer), which will perform the heavy tasks you may have, and load them into [Redis](https://redis.io/), which amazon also supports with [Amazon ElastiCache](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/?sc_channel=PS&sc_campaign=acquisition_AR&sc_publisher=google&sc_medium=english_elasticache_b&sc_content=elasticache_p&sc_detail=elasticache&sc_category=elasticache&sc_segment=160710928978&sc_matchtype=p&sc_country=AR&s_kwcid=AL!4422!3!160710928978!p!!g!!elasticache&ef_id=WLSNMAAABD@2bhzN:20170420234801:s). Then your web server instances will read that data from Redis.

This worker instance, is just a normal EC2 instance. You can create it the same way you created your other EC2 instances, you should probably label different, something like this:

[image]

**Note:** This is one of many ways to perform what you're asking, there are alternatives for all the services I listed, but to keep it "simple" I only provided AWS products which is what you're using.

Comment: Thanks. How can I have a worker EC2 instance? I already have a cluster with 12 container instances on ECS. Do I need to change anything in the AWS console? Or can I just write javascript code that will take care of this for me?

Comment: Sorry, I'm running ECS (Amazon EC2 Container Service), not EC2. Do you know how I would do this with that? Thank you!

Comment: @PythonNoobile I misread, I read the tag amazon-ec2 and went ahead. Let me get back to you when I get home :)

Comment: I can't talk. Not enough reputation :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142224/discussion-between-marcos-casagrande-and-pythonnoobile).

Comment: Is the problem that you are going to solve, is to populate in memory data store (periodically) and make it available for your web requests containers, for performance considerations? What is the read consistency requirements from cache ?

Comment: @Ashan Yes this is for performance reasons. Because we saw Redis lookups take almost 100 ms, which is too slow for our purposes. If we load the 11 million rows of Redis data into memory, the lookup will be much faster.

Comment: @Ashan We have ECS clusters, which contains servers written in Node.js. The main consideration is if loading 11 million rows of redis data into the server memory would or would not block the main node.js event loop. Our server gets hit over 100 times per second. So when we load the 11 million rows once every 5 minutes, we don't want it to be a blocking operation. Would it be async?